# Kernel driver i2c Develop

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

On my board I have an I2C device that sets some register.

```c
g_I2cDevFd = open("/dev/" UMAP_DEVNAME_I2C, O_RDWR, 0);
if (g_I2cDevFd < 0)
{
    HI_FATAL_I2C("open I2C err.\n");
    HI_I2C_UNLOCK();
    return HI_ERR_I2C_OPEN_ERR;
}
```

How can I do that?

Best Regards

Comment: This question is in a Review Queue. You should probably state the kernel version.

Comment: Linux-3.4.67 version.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear much. But for I2C communication in Linux Os, Please refer this link [Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices](http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices)

- Please use your device path in define `UMAP_DEVNAME_I2C` itself. ie, `#define  UMAP_DEVNAME_I2C "/dev/your_i2c_device"`
- Or use `sprintf` if you cant edit `UMAP_DEVNAME_I2C` ie,

  ```
  char buff[100] = {0}; // size you can change according to your requirement

  sprintf(buff,"/dev/%s",UMAP_DEVNAME_I2C);
  g_I2cDevFd = open(buff, O_RDWR, 0);
  /* Error check for open here*/

  int addr = 0xFF;          // 0xFF is Invalid, Give I2C address of your device
  if (ioctl(g_I2cDevFd, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
      printf("Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave.\n");
      /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
      exit(1);
  }

  /* Write or Read*/
  ```

Comment: thank U.I want to control the device of i2c in the user space. Can you provide more info on the i2c problem. i'm a novice.

Comment: yeah, it worked,thx, refer the link [Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices](http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices)